# Add string or symbol before and after the list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers and want to add character or symbol before and after the list.

I just want to add **array(** in the beginning and **)** in the end of list_1. I tried the following:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x = 'array('
y = ')'
a = str(x) + list_1 + str(y)
```

but it give me error :cannot concatenate str and list

My expected output is

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: `a = str(x) + str(list_1) + str(y)` works but why are you trying to do what you are trying to do?

Comment: `a = f'array(list_1)'`

Comment: the way you're trying to do will give you a string `'array([1, 2, 3, 4])`', if you want to convert a list to array, try `numpy.array(iist_1)`

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia Thanks a lot. I just want to use this output as input for another algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either `a = x + str(list_1) + y` or `f"array({list_1})"`. The latter is a debugged version of the suggestion by @sahasrara62.

The reason you got the error is, well, you can't concatenate str and list as the error message says. In your code, you are asking python to add a string `x` and a list `list_1`, which python cannot do. (By the way `x` and `y` are already strings, so `str(x)` and `str(y)` do nothing. They are just `x` and `y` respectively.) You need to explicitly convert the list into string by using `str(list_1)`. After that you can now concatenate it with other strings such as `x` and `y`.